# First Row activate Works only in activate all button jQuery c#

Tags: c#, jquery

This is my c# code for Activate all button:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void ActivateSelected(String Id)
    {
        clsCategoryBL objproject = new clsCategoryBL();
        string[] arr = Id.Split(',');
        string strid = arr[2];

        foreach (var id in arr)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                objproject.CategoryStatus(Convert.ToInt32(strid), true);

            }
        }
        BindDatatable();
    }
```

This is my jquery table bind code:

```
 function ActivateSelected() {
         var ids = '';
         var cells = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("example1").getElementsByTagName('td'));
         debugger;
         for (var i in cells) {

             var inputArray = cells[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
             for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                 if (inputArray[i].type == 'checkbox' && inputArray[i].checked == true) {
                     debugger;
                     ids += inputArray[i].id + ',';
                 }
             }
         }
         debugger;
         var urldata = "Category.aspx/ActivateSelected";
         $.ajax(

             {

                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",



                 dataType: "json",
                 async: "true",
                 cache: "false",
                 url: urldata,
                 data: "{Id:'" + ids + "'}",
                 success: function (dt) {
                     debugger;


                     location.reload();
                     $("#example1").DataTable();

                     //$("#example1").bind;
                     debugger;
                 },
                 error: function (result) {
                     alert("Error");
                     //console.log();
                     //alert(result);
                 }
             });

     }
```

The problem is that when select all the checkbox and click on Activate all button only First row status is activate instead of All row status,So kindly help me out.
This is my activate all button:

```
 <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" name="activatebtn" onclick='ActivateSelected();' style='font-size:22px;margin-left: 32px;color:green'>Activate Selected</i>
```

This is the code for select all the checkbox:

```
function Selectallcheckbox() {
         var cells = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("example1").getElementsByTagName('td'));
         var check = document.getElementById('chkall');
         if (check.checked) {
             for (var i in cells) {
                 var inputArray = cells[i].getElementsByClassName('chk');
                 for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                     inputArray[i].checked = true;
                 }
             }
         }
         else {
             for (var i in cells) {
                 var inputArray = cells[i].getElementsByClassName('chk');
                 for (var i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
                     inputArray[i].checked = false;
                 }
             }

         }
     }
```

I think the problem is here(c#):

```
 string strid = arr[2];
```

In strid only one id is comes..and only one id is binding in

```
objproject.CategoryStatus(Convert.ToInt32(strid), true);
```

If i am using Id instead of strid on above line it provides me error due to last comma..input string was not in correct format..

Comment: does all the ids come in to the Web Method `ActivateSelected()`.Put a breakpoint on the webmethod and check the `Id` passed on to it .

Comment: yes....all the id are coming @AshleyJohn

Comment: Then edit this line to `objproject.CategoryStatus(Convert.ToInt32(id), true);`I have changed `strid` to `id` the foreach loop variable.

Comment: input string was not in  correct format..error comes..@AshleyJohn...I think due to last comma..how can i handle

Comment: can you show me the `Id` that is being passed to the WebMethod

Comment: this way 59,58,57,

Comment: This is my problem...how to handle error..@AshleyJohn

Comment: `Id.Split(',');` should take care of it .The `arr` should contain only integers.Please verify that .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117161/discussion-between-ashley-john-and-manoj-maharana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this line to `objproject.CategoryStatus(Convert.ToInt32(id), true);` I have changed `strid` to `id` the foreach loop variable.